# In Craft 3, how to clear stuck "Deleting Stale Template Caches"

Tags: craft3, stalled-tasks

I've got 12 pending tasks, and can't get rid of the first stuck one.

- `CP->Utilities->Clear Caches` doesn't seem to help.
- In the database, in `craft_queue` there were five rows, the first one seeming to be the stuck one. I deleted all of those

Still the first task is stuck, and by now there are 14 tasks waiting.
I see that `craft_templatecachequeries` has over 11,000 rows. Would those be helpful to delete?

Comment: Can't you delete them in your Database  interface (phpmyadmin /adminer...) ? If not delete them via Craft query

Comment: @RobinSchambach Thanks, I did that, but things haven't changed. Question updated with additional info.

Comment: Could you please tell us the name of that task? They should not reappear when you delete them

Comment: Thank you, @RobinSchambach, it was a dumb mistake. I deleted them from the wrong database (staging instead of development). Progressing now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was, to delete the first row of the `queue` table *in the correct database*.
Also, it helped to increase `max_execution_time` in /etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini